# Is there any solutions to write this SAS code into "proc sql" process?

Tags: sql, sas

I wrote this code below to complete 2 tasks:

1. change the value of variable "miscrit" into null if satisfy the condition of "('01JUL2019'd - EXVISDAT + 1) < OverDueDays".
2. Then delete the columns of targetdays and overduedays from the table.

I wonder if it is possible to write this process with a "proc sql" process since I'm really interested in sql process these days.

Thanks for your help, everyone!

```
data test4;
    set test3;
    if ('01JUL2019'd - EXVISDAT + 1) < OverDueDays then do;
    miscrit="";
    end;
    drop targetdays overduedays;
run;
```

I managed to use proc sql to change the value of variable. But don't know how to add the code of the delete of targetdays and overduedays columns from this table.

```
proc sql;
    update test05
    set miscrit = ""
    where ('01JUL2019'd - EXVISDAT + 1) < OverDueDays
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: I think your code should work.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: What educational, tutorial or reference material are you using to learn SQL ?

Comment: Are you trying to do this for efficiency gains or learning SQL?

Comment: I'm just trying to use proc sql to solve some particular tasks that I used data procedure to manage before. ;-)  To learn some new codes during the problem-solving process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [alter table](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n1ckvfae6xf2tyn1nrivm6egpr8b.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en):

```
proc sql;
    update test05
    set miscrit = ""
    where ('01JUL2019'd - EXVISDAT + 1) < OverDueDays
    ;
    alter table test05
    drop targetdays,overduedays;
quit;
```